# ndiff returns a delta while none exists

Tags: python, difflib

I have two log files that I am trying to compare, in `bash`:

```
$ diff logfile_56.log logfile_57.log
```

returns nothing.

However, when I do the following with `difflib.ndiff` I get the following:

```
import difflib

with ('logfile_56.log', 'r') as file_one:
    content_one = file_one.readlines()

with ('logfile_57.log', 'r') as file_two:
    content_two = file_two.readlines()

delta = difflib.ndiff(content_one, content_two)

if len(list(delta)) == 0:
    print('Diff exists!')
```

This shows me that a diff exists, even when there isn't one. Although I see no '+' or '-' in the output and just the content of logfile_57.log instead. How should I be successfully detecting whether a diff exists or not? I can check the `delta` variable for `+` or `-` but, it is likely that the contents of either of these files would contain those characters anyway.

I'd like to use `ndiff` because the output when a diff does exist is something that works perfectly for my use case.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do the files end with a newline?  If they don't then they are treated as binary files and diff does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that zero-sized list of the differences means THERE ARE NO DIFFERENCES!

```
if len(list(delta)) == 0:
    print('Diff exists!')
```

Maybe if you replace `==` with `!=` ...